# How can I create a div and set a class attribute in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have this code and it works with javascript, I want to create a div and a class, how can I do the same with angular?

```
buildPhotoStruct() {
          var rowContainer = document.getElementById("row-container");
    
          var photoContainer = document.createElement("div");
          photoContainer.className = "photo-container"; 
          
          var photoDiv = document.createElement("div");
          photoDiv.className = "photo"; 
    
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = '../../assets/img/leopard.jpg';
    
          var button = document.createElement('button');
    
          photoDiv.appendChild(img);
          photoContainer.appendChild(photoDiv);
          photoContainer.appendChild(button);
          rowContainer.appendChild(photoContainer);
      }
```

Comment: Check https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#renderer2

Comment: you probably need to read up on Angular's docs for image and src attributes. 

angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

angular https://angular.io/guide/property-binding

Comment: Just create a component for this, structure how you want, if its for adding multiple  based on a list you can use ngFor on the component and just fill the data as needed